# How to set maximum directory size on apache server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, web-server, ftp

I create FTP users with a  php script. I would like to give my users unique FTP folders. However I would like to `limit` the folders sizes to `1024MB/folder`. How can I limit a folder size?

I use `proftp` with `i-mscp`. I create SQL rows for my FTP users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux - quota per directory?](http://serverfault.com/questions/100596/linux-quota-per-directory)

Comment: I thing, I don't need partitions for my FTP folders.

Comment: I have got a free filesharing webpage. I would like to let the users upload with ftp. However my users can upload 1024 large files maximum. I would like to let them 1024MB FTP upload / day.

Comment: Now you're making it more confusing. Are you limiting the folder size, or the traffic per day?

Comment: "free filesharing webpage" -- You don't have root on this box?  Well.  Good luck with that.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with box. But that is my own server. It would be enough to limit traffic / day / user, but it's maybe better to limit the size of folder. Somehow I need to limit them...:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux supports quotas for any applications which use the OS user for authentication / session / authorization. Googling for 'Linux quotas' turns up lots of good tutorials in the first page of matches.

And the good thing about using proper OS users / OS quotas is that you can continue to maintain the upload / storage functionality while you provide other methods of managing files and phase out FTP which is a dangerous and stupid protocol that belongs in the past.

Comment: What do you thing about this one? http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/47
Should it work? 

My users ask me for FTP protocol... :-s

Comment: Does quota means automaticaly delete files that larger than quota?

Comment: No it doesn't delete files it just won't allow you to create more when you reach the quota. As to which tutorial to read - read several.

Answer (score 1):

[Setting FTP quotas with ProFTPd](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Quotas.html).  You should be able to work it out from there.

Comment: I don't thing I need new partitions. I have got options to make limit of my users webpage sizes. 100MB / host, or 1024Mb/host.. etc. However the don't own partitions. Somehow simple apache software do it. OR not?

Comment: Probably not.  At least not with any mechanism I've come across so far.  Apache is a great webserver.. less so for managing directory usage.  You could probably write something in PHP *shudder*